# One sided circle div

Tags: html, css

I would like to create something like representing in the picture. I've tried different methods but none is delivering my expectation. I'm not sure how, does anyone have any idea how it should be done? https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrb7f.png

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: The problem is solved, I tried doing 2 different divs, one rectangle and one circle and tried to blend them in, tried the method with border radius but as I mentioned, did it with percentages and gave me a more of elliptical form.. But the easy answer is that should have used px's.. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `border-top-left-radius` and
`border-bottom-left-radius`:

```css
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: i know this is not necessary but i suggest always closing a div element like <div></div>

Comment: Oh well, I tried the one that you posted too but instead of pixels on the border radius I used percentages.. And it gave me more of a eliptical form.. Now it's perfect and can manage it for different heights and widths. Thanks